# How do I auto-populate some fields on every new lead created

Tags: visualforce, leads, fields

For example, I would like to auto-populate:

- Decision Timeframe = Immediate
- Decision Maker = Yes (checkbox)
- Has Budget = Yes (checkbox)
- Lead Priority = High Priority
- Lead Queality = 5 stars.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set up default values for your fields. This is detailed in the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_default_field_values.htm&language=en_US) and [here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_default_values.htm&language=en_US).

Default field settings are available on one of the screens that appears when you are creating a field, to add them for existing fields use the Edit link next to the field name on the object's field settings screen.

> Use default field values to make your users more productive by reducing the number of fields they need to fill in manually. Default field values automatically insert the value of a custom field when a new record is created. A default value can be based on a formula for some types of fields or exact values such as Checked or Unchecked for checkbox fields.

Comment: Default values are one of the options you will scroll through on creating a new field on Lead. Clicking on "edit" next to the field name in setup will return you to setting these options.

Comment: Note that if the default values are dynamic, e.g.  val = f(x,y), then x,y must come from the running user or environment, not from other lead fields (perhaps sync'd from a marketing automation system). Otherwise, you'll need a VF controller and an override of the Lead.New button and/or workflows and/or triggers - depending on the use case.